# Haskell function process

Tags: haskell

```
integerList = [1] ++ integerList

(head (tail integerList))
```

I have run this code and the result is `1` and that it is an endless recursion.
I am trying to figure out how haskell calculates these functions. Can someone write down the process. I would like to visualize it. Thanks!

Comment: The keyword is [lazy evaluation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation).

Comment: ok so from my understanding this is what i think is happening.  head (tail  [1,1] ++ integerList)?

Comment: maybe it is like this instead: head (tail [1] ++  ([1] ++ integerList))?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. `head (x : _) = x` and `tail (_ : xs) = xs`, so a function equivalent to `head (tail x)` could be defined as `f (x : (y : _)) = y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` returns the first element of a list. In this case it returns the first element of the list `tail integerList`. `tail` returns the original list without the first element. The original list is `integerList` which is bound to `[1] ++ integerList`. The `++` operator concatenates two lists, so the resulting list is `1 : integerList`. Applying `tail` to this list gives `integerList`, so `tail integerList` simply yields `integerList`.

Back to the beginning: substitute `tail integerList` with `integerList` (since that's what it evaluates to) to get `head integerList`. Reminder: `integerList` evaluates to `1 : integerList`. Applying `head` to that we get `1`.

Comment: The key point to notice is that `++` doesn't need to evaluate `integerList` *at all* in order to return `1 : integerList`.

Comment: Thank you d3dave. It makes perfect sense now! :) appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Let’s expand the definitions:

```
integerList = [1] ++ integerList
integerList = foldr (:) integerList [1]  -- inline (++)
integerList = 1 : integerList            -- inline foldr
```

Now it should be clear that `integerList` is a cyclical linked list, representing an infinite stream of ones:

```
                  __________
                 /          \
                |           |
                V           |
              +---+---+---+ |
integerList = | : | o | o | |
              +---+-|-+-|-+ |
                    |   \___/
                    V
                  +---+
                  | 1 |
                  +---+
```

Just as if you had written the following C:

```
struct Cell { int head; struct Cell *tail; };

struct Cell *integerList = malloc(sizeof(struct Cell));
integerList->head = 1;
integerList->tail = integerList;
```

The `tail` of `integerList` is `integerList`, and the `head` is `1`. You can manipulate infinite streams with many standard prelude functions such as `take`, `dropWhile`, `foldr`, and so on. For example, `take 5 integerList` produces `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. You can also define `integerList` using the `repeat` function: `integerList = repeat 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome visual guide! :)